# Test disappears from test explorer when calling native code in C++ CLI test project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, mstest, mixed-mode

I have a C++ CLI test project in Visual Studio 2013 that calls native code;

```
    [TestMethod]
    void Test1()
    {
        int R1, R2;
        R1 = R2 = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

        R1 = SyncPort::OpenPort(Channel, ReceiveChan, PortID, NominalBaud);
        R2 = SyncPort::OpenPort(Channel, SendChan, PortID, NominalBaud);

        Assert::AreEqual(spSuccess, R1);
        Assert::AreEqual(spSuccess, R2);
    };
```

For some reason, when I add the two `OpenPort` calls, the test disappears from Test Explorer and cannot be run. If I comment them out, the test appears again.

The `SyncPort` class is defined in a separate .LIB that is statically linked into the test project. If I define a mock replica class that has the same signature locally, it works. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't MSTest like me adding external native functions in a test?

Comment: Do you have all necessary dlls in the test's bin-folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was cause by the `SyncPort` assembly having a missing delay-loaded dependency. Therefore the syntax was correct but it would never load. The test detection engine loads the test assembly in the background after compilation, which attempts to load the `SyncPort` assembly and fails.

The solution was to fix the dependency issue and it all falls into place.